# What happened to the Tor downloads? Is there a safe alternative site to download from?

Tags: configuration

https://www.torproject.org/download/download

I get the following error: The requested URL /torbrowser/4.0.6/torbrowser-install-4.0.6_en-US.exe was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2):

This is a transient error while a new version of TorBrowser is uploaded. The issue is currently being fixed. Just try again in a little while and everything should work again.